# Prefer code fences or indenting?

Tags: discussion, code-formatting, code, code-block

Personally, code fences are cleaner (less whitespace) and are parsed more quickly due to the ability to hint at the language via `cpp`,`lang-none`,`js`, etc.

**Other than requiring indenting to use code in lists, is there a documented rule preferring one over the other?**

Note, I am not asking about *how* to indent or display code in a code fence.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/282094), or   https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193990/should-the-formatting-style-be-mimicked-when-editing-posts or  https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146236/282094

Comment: @Rob No. I am not asking how to display text as code. I'm asking if users prefer one style over the other.

Comment: Well that would be an opinion based question, which would be off-topic.

Comment: Code fences are 'relatively' new (and hinting too - but not as much) so it might also be a matter of how used you are to the old and new ways

Comment: @Luuklag "Is there a documented rule preferring one over the other" isn't an opinion-based question.

Comment: Rather than reading the first link as "how do I" you should refer to the answer, which suggests that "you **should** ..." [dupe **FAQ** on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/3648282). The second link offers two duplicate links in the banner, which offer helpful suggestions. The third link is simply "should it be automated ...", which leads to problems with the code pasted not being equal to the code on the question asker's computer; so you ought to [prettify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pretty-print) your code before you run it; and copypaste *that* if you need help.

Comment: The preference seems to be to fence correctly idented code, sources: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125148/282094  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388213/3648282 https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/19300/914627   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_style

Comment: Parsed more quickly by whom or what?

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q The proper code highlighting appears faster because the parser doesn't have to guess what language it is.

Comment: Stack Snippets still use html comments for language. If performance was an issue  it would make sense they would have been converted. I can't see how parsing a fence vs parsing html comments makes much difference